# Show the player's score in game and update it

Tags: python, timer, pygame, display

I'm new to programming and I'm currently working on a game what's like the game squirrel where you eat others who are smaller than you and get damage of larger ones. I now wanted to display the player's size, which will do it perfectly but it displays only the start size. So when I ate a foe I want that the number changes but I can't figure out how.

```
    def main():
    global FPSCLOCK, DISPLAYSURF, BASICFONT, L_SQUIR_IMG, R_SQUIR_IMG, GRASSIMAGES, MEL, MER, L_SQUIR_IMG2, R_SQUIR_IMG2

    pygame.init()
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load('cat.png'))
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINWIDTH, WINHEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Space CAT')
    BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)

    # load the image files
    MEL = pygame.image.load("cat.png")
    MER = pygame.transform.flip(MEL, True, False)

    L_SQUIR_IMG = pygame.image.load("foe1.png")
    R_SQUIR_IMG = pygame.transform.flip(L_SQUIR_IMG, True, False)

    L_SQUIR_IMG2 = pygame.image.load("spacemouse2.png")
    R_SQUIR_IMG2 = pygame.transform.flip(L_SQUIR_IMG2, True, False)

    GRASSIMAGES = []
    for i in range(1, 5):
        GRASSIMAGES.append(pygame.image.load("grass%s.png" % i))

    while True:
        runGame()


def runGame():
    # set up variables for the start of a new game
    invulnerableMode = False  # if the player is invulnerable
    invulnerableStartTime = 0 # time the player became invulnerable
    gameOverMode = False      # if the player has lost
    gameOverStartTime = 0     # time the player lost
    winMode = False           # if the player has won
    Level2 = False          # if Level 2 is reached       
    # create the surfaces to hold game text
    gameOverSurf = BASICFONT.render('Game Over', True, WHITE)
    gameOverRect = gameOverSurf.get_rect()
    gameOverRect.center = (HALF_WINWIDTH, HALF_WINHEIGHT)

    winSurf = BASICFONT.render('You have achieved ALPHA CAT!', True, WHITE)
    winRect = winSurf.get_rect()
    winRect.center = (HALF_WINWIDTH, HALF_WINHEIGHT)

    winSurf2 = BASICFONT.render('(Press "r" to restart.)', True, WHITE)
    winRect2 = winSurf2.get_rect()
    winRect2.center = (HALF_WINWIDTH, HALF_WINHEIGHT + 30)

    winSurf3 = BASICFONT.render('You have reached Level 2', True, WHITE)
    winRect3 = winSurf3.get_rect()
    winRect3.center = (HALF_WINWIDTH, HALF_WINHEIGHT)

    # camerax and cameray are the top left of where the camera view is
    camerax = 0
    cameray = 0

    grassObjs = []    # stores all the star objects in the game
    squirrelObjs = [] # stores all the non-player fish objects
    squirrelObjs2 = [] #stores all the non-player mouse objects
    # stores the player object:
    playerObj = {'surface': pygame.transform.scale(MEL, (STARTSIZE, STARTSIZE)),
                 'facing': LEFT,
                 'size': STARTSIZE,
                 'x': HALF_WINWIDTH,
                 'y': HALF_WINHEIGHT,
                 'bounce':0,
                 'health': MAXHEALTH}

    # show the player's score
    winSurf4 = BASICFONT.render(str(playerObj['size']), True, RED)
    winRect4 = winSurf4.get_rect()
    winRect4.center = (HALF_WINWIDTH + 680, HALF_WINHEIGHT - 420)

    moveLeft  = False
    moveRight = False
    moveUp    = False
    moveDown  = False

    # start off with some random grass images on the screen
    for i in range(7):
        grassObjs.append(makeNewGrass(camerax, cameray))
        grassObjs[i]['x'] = random.randint(0, WINWIDTH)
        grassObjs[i]['y'] = random.randint(0, WINHEIGHT)

    while True: # main game loop
        # Check if we should turn off invulnerability
        if invulnerableMode and time.time() - invulnerableStartTime > INVULNTIME:
            invulnerableMode = False



       #### move all the fish
        for sObj in squirrelObjs:
            # move the fish, and adjust for their bounce
            sObj['x'] += sObj['movex']
            sObj['y'] += sObj['movey']
            sObj['bounce'] += 0
            if sObj['bounce'] > sObj['bouncerate']:
                sObj['bounce'] = 0 # reset bounce amount

            # random chance they change direction
            if random.randint(0, 99) < DIRCHANGEFREQ:
                sObj['movex'] = getRandomVelocity()
                sObj['movey'] = getRandomVelocity()
                if sObj['movex'] > 0: # faces right
                    sObj['surface'] = pygame.transform.scale(R_SQUIR_IMG, (sObj['width'], sObj['height']))
                else: # faces left
                    sObj['surface'] = pygame.transform.scale(L_SQUIR_IMG, (sObj['width'], sObj['height']))




         #### move all the mice 
        for sObj2 in squirrelObjs2:
            # move the mice, and adjust for their bounce 
            sObj2['x'] += sObj2['movex']
            sObj2['y'] += sObj2['movey']
            sObj2['bounce'] += 0
            if sObj2['bounce'] > sObj2['bouncerate']:
                sObj2['bounce'] = 0 # reset bounce amount 

            # random chance they change direction
            if random.randint(0, 99) < DIRCHANGEFREQ:
                sObj2['movex'] = getRandomVelocity()
                sObj2['movey'] = getRandomVelocity()
                if sObj2['movex'] > 0: # faces right
                    sObj2['surface'] = pygame.transform.scale(R_SQUIR_IMG2, (sObj2['width'], sObj2['height']))
                else: # faces left
                    sObj2['surface'] = pygame.transform.scale(L_SQUIR_IMG2, (sObj2['width'], sObj2['height']))



        #### go through all the objects and see if any need to be deleted.(1)
        for i in range(len(grassObjs) - 1, -1, -1):
            if isOutsideActiveArea(camerax, cameray, grassObjs[i]):
                del grassObjs[i]
        for i in range(len(squirrelObjs) - 1, -1, -1):
            if isOutsideActiveArea(camerax, cameray, squirrelObjs[i]):
                del squirrelObjs[i]

        #### go through all the objects and see if any need to be deleted.(2)
        for i in range(len(squirrelObjs2) - 1, -1, -1):
            if isOutsideActiveArea(camerax, cameray, squirrelObjs2[i]):
                del squirrelObjs2[i]

        #### add more stars & foes if we don't have enough.
        while len(grassObjs) < NUMGRASS:
            grassObjs.append(makeNewGrass(camerax, cameray))
        if Level2 == False:
            while len(squirrelObjs) < NUMSQUIRRELS:
                squirrelObjs.append(makeNewFish(camerax, cameray))
        #### Level 2 spawn mouse
        if Level2 == True:
            while len(squirrelObjs2) < NUMSQUIRRELS:
                squirrelObjs2.append(makeNewMice(camerax, cameray))


        # adjust camerax and cameray if beyond the "camera slack"
        playerCenterx = playerObj['x'] + int(playerObj['size'] / 2)
        playerCentery = playerObj['y'] + int(playerObj['size'] / 2)
        if (camerax + HALF_WINWIDTH) - playerCenterx > CAMERASLACK:
            camerax = playerCenterx + CAMERASLACK - HALF_WINWIDTH
        elif playerCenterx - (camerax + HALF_WINWIDTH) > CAMERASLACK:
            camerax = playerCenterx - CAMERASLACK - HALF_WINWIDTH
        if (cameray + HALF_WINHEIGHT) - playerCentery > CAMERASLACK:
            cameray = playerCentery + CAMERASLACK - HALF_WINHEIGHT
        elif playerCentery - (cameray + HALF_WINHEIGHT) > CAMERASLACK:
            cameray = playerCentery - CAMERASLACK - HALF_WINHEIGHT

        # draw the black background
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(GRASSCOLOR)

        # draw all the grass objects on the screen
        for gObj in grassObjs:
            gRect = pygame.Rect( (gObj['x'] - camerax,
                                  gObj['y'] - cameray,
                                  gObj['width'],
                                  gObj['height']) )
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(GRASSIMAGES[gObj['grassImage']], gRect)


        ### draw the fish
        for sObj in squirrelObjs:
            sObj['rect'] = pygame.Rect( (sObj['x'] - camerax,
                                         sObj['y'] - cameray - getBounceAmount(sObj['bounce'], sObj['bouncerate'], sObj['bounceheight']),
                                         sObj['width'],
                                         sObj['height']) )
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(sObj['surface'], sObj['rect'])

        ### draw the mice
        for sObj2 in squirrelObjs2:
            sObj2['rect'] = pygame.Rect( (sObj2['x'] - camerax,
                                         sObj2['y'] - cameray - getBounceAmount(sObj2['bounce'], sObj2['bouncerate'], sObj2['bounceheight']),
                                         sObj2['width'],
                                         sObj2['height']) )
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(sObj2['surface'], sObj2['rect'])




        ### draw the player
        flashIsOn = round(time.time(), 1) * 10 % 2 == 1
        if not gameOverMode and not (invulnerableMode and flashIsOn):
            playerObj['rect'] = pygame.Rect( (playerObj['x'] - camerax,
                                              playerObj['y'] - cameray - getBounceAmount(playerObj['bounce'], BOUNCERATE, BOUNCEHEIGHT),
                                              playerObj['size'],
                                              playerObj['size']) )
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(playerObj['surface'], playerObj['rect'])


        ### draw the health meter
        drawHealthMeter(playerObj['health'])

        for event in pygame.event.get(): # event handling loop
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()

            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key in (K_UP, K_w):
                    moveDown = False
                    moveUp = True
                elif event.key in (K_DOWN, K_s):
                    moveUp = False
                    moveDown = True
                elif event.key in (K_LEFT, K_a):
                    moveRight = False
                    moveLeft = True
                    if playerObj['facing'] != LEFT: # change player image
                        playerObj['surface'] = pygame.transform.scale(MEL, (playerObj['size'], playerObj['size']))
                    playerObj['facing'] = LEFT
                elif event.key in (K_RIGHT, K_d):
                    moveLeft = False
                    moveRight = True
                    if playerObj['facing'] != RIGHT: # change player image
                        playerObj['surface'] = pygame.transform.scale(MER, (playerObj['size'], playerObj['size']))
                    playerObj['facing'] = RIGHT
                elif winMode and event.key == K_r:
                    return

            elif event.type == KEYUP:
                # stop moving the player
                if event.key in (K_LEFT, K_a):
                    moveLeft = False
                elif event.key in (K_RIGHT, K_d):
                    moveRight = False
                elif event.key in (K_UP, K_w):
                    moveUp = False
                elif event.key in (K_DOWN, K_s):
                    moveDown = False

                elif event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    terminate()

        if not gameOverMode:
            # actually move the player
            if moveLeft:
                playerObj['x'] -= MOVERATE
            if moveRight:
                playerObj['x'] += MOVERATE
            if moveUp:
                playerObj['y'] -= MOVERATE
            if moveDown:
                playerObj['y'] += MOVERATE

            if (moveLeft or moveRight or moveUp or moveDown) or playerObj['bounce'] != 0:
                playerObj['bounce'] += 0

            if playerObj['bounce'] > BOUNCERATE:
                playerObj['bounce'] = 0 # reset bounce amount

            #### check if the player has collided with any fish
            for i in range(len(squirrelObjs)-1, -1, -1):
                sqObj = squirrelObjs[i]
                if 'rect' in sqObj and playerObj['rect'].colliderect(sqObj['rect']):
                    # a player/fish collision has occurred

                    if sqObj['width'] * sqObj['height'] <= playerObj['size']**2:
                        # player is larger and eats the fish
                        playerObj['size'] += int( (sqObj['width'] * sqObj['height'])**0.2 ) + 1

                        del squirrelObjs[i]


                        if playerObj['facing'] == LEFT:
                            playerObj['surface'] = pygame.transform.scale(MEL, (playerObj['size'], playerObj['size']))
                        if playerObj['facing'] == RIGHT:
                            playerObj['surface'] = pygame.transform.scale(MER, (playerObj['size'], playerObj['size']))
                        if playerObj['size'] > WINSIZE/2:
                            Level2 = True   # Turn on Level 2
                        if playerObj['size'] > WINSIZE:
                            winMode = True # turn on "win mode"

                    elif not invulnerableMode:
                        # player is smaller and takes damage
                        invulnerableMode = True
                        invulnerableStartTime = time.time()
                        playerObj['health'] -= 1
                        if playerObj['health'] == 0:
                            gameOverMode = True # turn on "game over mode"
                            gameOverStartTime = time.time()

            ### check if the player has collided with any mice
            for i in range(len(squirrelObjs2)-1, -1, -1):
                sqObj2 = squirrelObjs2[i]
                if 'rect' in sqObj2 and playerObj['rect'].colliderect(sqObj2['rect']):
                    # a player/mouse collision has occurred

                    if sqObj2['width'] * sqObj2['height'] <= playerObj['size']**2:
                        # player is larger and eats the mouse
                        playerObj['size'] += int( (sqObj2['width'] * sqObj2['height'])**0.2 ) + 1
                        del squirrelObjs2[i]


                        if playerObj['facing'] == LEFT:
                            playerObj['surface'] = pygame.transform.scale(MEL, (playerObj['size'], playerObj['size']))
                        if playerObj['facing'] == RIGHT:
                            playerObj['surface'] = pygame.transform.scale(MER, (playerObj['size'], playerObj['size']))

                        if playerObj['size'] > WINSIZE/2:
                            Level2 = True   # Turn on Level 2
                        if playerObj['size'] > WINSIZE:
                            winMode = True # turn on "win mode"

                    elif not invulnerableMode:
                        # player is smaller and takes damage
                        invulnerableMode = True
                        invulnerableStartTime = time.time()
                        playerObj['health'] -= 1
                        if playerObj['health'] == 0:
                            gameOverMode = True # turn on "game over mode"
                            gameOverStartTime = time.time()
        else:
            # game is over, show "game over" text
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(gameOverSurf, gameOverRect)
            if time.time() - gameOverStartTime > GAMEOVERTIME:
                return # end the current game

        # show the player's size
        if not winMode:
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(winSurf4, winRect4)

        # check if the player has reached level 2.
        if Level2 and playerObj['size'] < WINSIZE/2+10:
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(winSurf3, winRect3)

        # check if the player has won.
        if winMode:
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(winSurf, winRect)
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(winSurf2, winRect2)

        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: render the text in the event loop?

Answer (score 0):

Your code rendering the size is:

```
winSurf4 = BASICFONT.render(str(playerObj['size']), True, RED)
winRect4 = winSurf4.get_rect()
winRect4.center = (HALF_WINWIDTH + 680, HALF_WINHEIGHT - 420)
```

You call it only at the beginning of the program, so the score is displayed only once.
Just move this code to your main loop:

```
while True:
    (...)        
    winSurf4 = BASICFONT.render(str(playerObj['size']), True, RED)
    winRect4 = winSurf4.get_rect()
    winRect4.center = (HALF_WINWIDTH + 680, HALF_WINHEIGHT - 420)
    (...)
```

The score will be refreshed at every iteration. This will do the job, but it is probably unnecessary. It would be best to execute this routine only when the score changes internally, so as to reduce the unnecessary execution of code.